# Sequence contains more than one element an NancyBootstrapperBase class

Tags: unit-testing, exception, nancy

I can't figure out why this exception was threw...
I have a unit test:

```cs
[Test]
public void Should_return_status_ok_when_route_exists()
{
    // Given
    var bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBootstrapper();
    var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

    // When
    var result = browser.Get("/", with =>
                                        {
                                            with.HttpRequest();
                                        });
    // Then
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);

}
```

While browser variable was assigning, the exception threw in Nancy Bootstrapper Base class with follow stack trace

System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains more than one element

```
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source)
at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.GetRootPathProvider() in NancyBootstrapperBase.cs: line 558
at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.get_RootPathProvider() in NancyBootstrapperBase.cs: line 172
at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.GetAdditionalInstances() in NancyBootstrapperBase.cs: line 514
at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.Initialise() in NancyBootstrapperBase.cs: line 242
at Nancy.Testing.Browser..ctor(INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper) in Browser.cs: line 39
at Tests.Tests.Should_return_status_ok_when_route_exists() in Tests.cs: line 34
```

Comment: Are you running Nancy.Testing from the same project that you application is in? If not, then are you referencing your hosting assembly (Nancy.Hosting.xxxx) from the project that also references Nancy.Testing ?

Comment: I didn't run Nancy.Testing at all. Should I do that? I just added Nancy, Nancy.Authentication.Forms, Nancy.Testing references to my test project and run tests I wrote using Resharper in VS. It is not correct?

Comment: If you only referenced Nancy, Nancy.Authentication.Forms and Nancy.Testing and got this problem when running your test, then we would need to know more about your project setup to know why it is happening. Is the code available anywhere?

Comment: I have this problem in "Instant Nancy Web Development [eBook]" chapter 4 code from book, but this book and code have copylaws :/

Comment: Ok. In my case, solution was to update all used nuget package to newest version (open nuget form manager, and go to Updates tab and update your nugets ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem recently. I was testing my bootstrapper by trying to resolve the Nancy module like this:

```cs
[Test]
public void PushModule_Is_Resolvable()
{
  var pushModule = mUnderTest.GetModule(typeof (PushModule), new NancyContext());
  Assert.That(pushModule, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

This yielded the exception described in the question. After reading Chris' answer I just configured that dll not to be copied to the output folder in Visual Studio:

- Find the Nancy.Hosting.Self reference in the project that is tested.
- Right-click the reference and choose "Properties".
- Set **Copy Local** to **false**.
- Clean and rebuild your solution.

This solved the issue for me.
I would have posted this as a comment to Chris' answer but since this is my very first post I can only post answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this with Nancy 0.16.1 on a fresh test assembly which references Nancy, Nancy.Testing and a project reference (in VS2010) to the main service assembly which contains my Modules.

The service assembly references Nancy.Hosting.Self.

The build for the test assembly pulls in Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll to the build folder and the test fails with the error you describe.

Removing the Hosting dll from the build folder by hand resolves the error and the test goes green e.g. delete `MyTests\bin\Debug\Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll`

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same when testing with a project that refers to Nancy.Hosting.Self.

My workaround is to create a CustomBootstrapper and override RootPathProvider property.

```
    class TestBootStrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper{
    protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider {
        get {
            return new FakeRootPathProvider();
        }
    }
}
```